# Calling Javascript function from Code behind page

Tags: c#, javascript, function

I have a script that I want to pop a window after 5 page views. The java script works fine on the default.aspx page with a link to call it. But I want to launce it from my default.aspx.cs page after my session var count gets to 5.  How can I do this? Is it possible?

default.aspx

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.name = "Register";
    function popWin(link) {
        var w = window.open(link.href, link.target, 'width=500,height=600,resizable');
        return w ? false : true; // if popup blocker, use the default behaviour of the link 
    } 
</script>
```

Default.aspx.cs page

```
 if (Session["PagesViewed"].ToString() == "5")
            {
              //Call my Javascript function How?????

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can output javascript into a [`LiteralControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) from your code behind:

.aspx:

```
<asp:Literal id="myLiteral" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
myLiteral.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>popWin('url');</script>";
```

When rendered this way, the output script will call the function - make sure it is lower in the page than where the function was defined to ensure it exists.

Comment: I tried the code above and i get this error. Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'popWin' is undefined

Comment: @CsharpBeginner Put the `<asp:Literal ... />` after your script, as mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.Net you can do the following:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),
    "openpopup",
    "popWin('www.someurl.com');",
    True);
```

If you need more control over your scripts placement @Oded has a *better* approach - as trying to call a function that has not been defined isn't a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call javascript functions directly from C#. However, what you could do is pass a `<script>` to the browser that executes the function.

```
response.Write("<script>popWin(something);</script>");
```